# Find convergence in distribution limit of sequence of random variables

Tags: probability-theory, convergence-divergence, weak-convergence

I've been stuck with this problem for a while now:

Let $X$ and $Y$ be random variables, and define $Z_n := \frac{1}{n}X + (1-\frac{1}{n})Y$ for $n \in \mathbb{N}$, find its convergence in distribution limit.

My intuition tells me $Z_n$ would converge in distribution to $Y$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$, but I can't seem to write a formal argument. I've tried proving it converges to $Y$ in probability, by showing $$\lim_{n\to\infty}P(|Z_n-Y|>\varepsilon)=0 \Leftrightarrow \lim_{n\to\infty}P\left(\frac{|X-Y|}{n}>\varepsilon \right)=0$$

What could be a way of showing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: for any random variable $W$, what is $$\bigcap_{n =1}^\infty \{|W| > n \epsilon\}$$ ?